# Why does this name server resolve incorrectly?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, nslookup, dns-lookup

Why does this ENom name server resolve incorrectly? Earthlink is related to my ISP.

```
$ nslookup yahoo.com dns1.name-services.com
Server:  dns1.name-services.com
Address:  98.124.192.1

Name:    yahoo.com.earthlink.net
Address:  69.64.147.243


$ nslookup yahoo.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Name:    yahoo.com
Addresses:  98.139.183.24
          206.190.36.45
          98.138.253.109


$ nslookup dns1.name-services.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Name:    dns1.name-services.com
Address:  98.124.192.1
```

Comment: dns1.name-services.com is not a recursive DNS server, you can't lookup yahoo.com against it

Comment: Recursive DNS: http://dyn.com/blog/recursive-dns-how-does-it-work/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it isn't resolving it.  However, the reason that it is appending earthlink.net to yahoo.com is because, after not finding the record for yahoo.com (probably for the reason @devicenull mentioned), it is appending a default domain (in this case earthlink.net) because the nslookup request wasn't terminated in a "."

The following will return more valid results from what your dns server is finding (note the trailing "." on yahoo.com.

nslookup yahoo.com. dns1.name-services.com

Hope that helps,

Hal

Comment: `*** No all records (ANY) records available for yahoo.com.`

Comment: To clarify: nslookup queries for yahoo.com.earthlink.net first then queries for yahoo.com because the trailing dot was omitted, not the other way around. You can easily see this behavior by running nslookup in debug mode.